# Unable to find Unable to find package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to install the package(Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer) using Package Manager Console in my WPF.Net Application Visual Studio 2017 and i got this error.

> Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

install entityframework not entityframeworkCore. entityframeworkCore is for .net core and won't work on standart .net application

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but I can't find entityframework in my nuget package manager and I also can't install it using the console.

Answer (score 0):

Closing all open Visual Studio windows and reopening the project worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added correct nuget source. You can see it using `dotnet nuget list source`

For me adding below nuget source solved the issue :
`dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org`